# How to share iPhone application video on You Tube?

Tags: ios, youtube, gdata-api

I am uploading video on YouTube from my app.
I have followed these steps http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/

But  i am getting 19 errors of not finding library classes in that sample code.

In GDataOAuthViewControllerTouch.m file getting error "expected a type" for GDataOAuthAuthentication class. This is snap shot 
[image]

I have also tried these steps http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/ , but in that if i use gdata client library which provided by urinieto sample code than also getting errors.

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting a question, I'd heartily encourage you to provide specifics (e.g., you you're getting error messages, tell us _precisely_, word for word, what the error messages say by cutting and pasting the errors into your question). Are they linking errors? Compile errors? You must be more specific if you want us to help you. Please edit your original question, providing more specifics.